# Delete Item form DB out of ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I scrolled through many questions, but i didn'tget it or just found unspecific answers.

So i got an SQLite Database and Display the content of it in a ListView. I extract the Content of the database and Display it as a String. Now if i click on one of the items i want to delete it from the database. So i found out that i have to use an `OnItemClick` Adapter. But how can i get the item i clicked and the object that's behind the String in the ListView to then pass it to the db to delete it?

Greatings

This is my method to Display the data in the ListView

```
  List<TaskData> TaskList = datasource.getAllTasks();
    //Daten werden im ArrayAdapter gespeichert
    ArrayAdapter<TaskData> TaskListArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, TaskList);

    ListView TaskDataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TaskListView);
    TaskDataListView.setAdapter(TaskListArrayAdapter);
    TaskDataListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            datasource.open();
            datasource.deleteTask();
            datasource.close();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my TaskData class

```
public class TaskData {
public long id;
public String type;
public String name;
public String owner;
public String expiration;

public TaskData(long id, String type, String name, String owner, String expiration) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.expiration = expiration;
}

public String toString() {
    return " Typ: " + type + " Name: " + name + " Owner: " + owner + " Until: " + expiration;
}
public long getId(){return id;}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your code?help us to  help you

Comment: use where clause with available data or use customize adapter

Comment: i added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the **`onItemClick`** method **position** will be the position of the clicked Item. This equates to the index(element) of the Tasklist that was clicked.

So you could use `long clickedid = TaskList.get(position).getId();` and this would retrieve the id of the task.

Or assuming that the `deleteTask` method uses the id to identify the row to be deleted then :-

```
        datasource.deleteTask(TaskList.get(position).getid());
```